# How to use lambda as std::unique_ptr's Deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Check following contrived program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
using UniPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

int* alloc()
{
    return new int;
}

UniPtr<int> func()
{
    auto dealloc = [](int* p){delete p;};

    return UniPtr<int>{alloc(), dealloc};
}

int main()
{
    auto p = func();
    return 0;
}
```

From [std::function constructor manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), I think constructing `std::function` object may throw exception, even the ratio is very low:

```
UniPtr<int> func()
{
    auto dealloc = [](int* p){delete p;};

    return UniPtr<int>{alloc(), dealloc};
}
```

But if using function pointer instead of `std::function` object:

```
template<typename T>
using UniPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>;
```

I think after leaving the `func()` scope, the `dealloc` object should be freed, and it can't be referenced. Please correct me if I am wrong. So the only safe method I can come out is defining a global `dealloc` function:

```
void dealloc(int* p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

But I don't like this method.

Based on precedent exposition, there is not 100% safe way to use `lambda` as [std::unique_ptr's Deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), Or I misunderstand something? How to use `lambda` as `std::unique_ptr`'s `Deleter`?

Comment: What do you mean by *Based on precedent exposition, there is not 100% safe way to use lambda as std::unique_ptr's Deleter*? What part of the linked page are you referring to?

Comment: I don't see why `dealloc` needs to be *global*; if your only concern is that it remain referenceable after `func()` exits, then can't you just declare it `static`?

Comment: @ruakh: You mean "`static auto dealloc = [](int* p){delete p;};`"? Yeah, I can't come out this idea before, thanks!

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry my poor English confused you. I mean construcing `lambda` to `std::function` object may throw exception.

Comment: @NanXiao Yes, true, it could. But most, probably all, `std::function` implementations make use of small buffer optimization to avoid dynamic memory allocation for small callables. A captureless lambda would almost certainly fall into that category.

Comment: Using a lambda for a deleter (or even a named function) adds a little bit of overhead to the unique_ptr. If you use a functor `struct dealloc{ void operator()(int *p) { delete p; } };` then `std::unique_ptr<int, dealloc>` is a zero-cost abstraction against. You should keep that in mind.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for your comments! But using `struct dealloc` in `std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>` has the potential issue of throwing exception in constructing functor, correct? Thanks!

Comment: Read more carefully please. I didn't write `std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>`, I wrote `std::unique_ptr<int, dealloc>`. I don't see what exceptions have to do with the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ah, I get your idea! I misunderstood your idea before. Very sorry!

Comment: Is it even allowed to use a `std::function` object as deleter? `std::unique_ptr` constructor requires that Deleter is nothrow-CopyConstructible. That is not the case for `std::function`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr (3-4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think after leaving the `func()` scope, the `dealloc` object should be freed, and it can't be referenced.

You don't need to worry about it. Yes the lambda object will be destroyed, but the pointer to function returned by the [lambda's function pointer conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator_ret.28.2A.29.28params.29.28.29) is always valid, it won't become dangled.

> The value returned by this conversion function is a pointer to a function with C++ language linkage that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure object's function call operator directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you defined `UniPtr` as

```
template<typename T>
using UniPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>;
```

then the following code is valid, there are no concerns about the lifetime of the deleter

```
UniPtr<int> func()
{
    auto dealloc = [](int* p){delete p;};
    return UniPtr<int>{alloc(), dealloc};
}
```

Quoting N3337, [*expr.prim.lambda/6*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.lambda#6)

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* with no *lambda-capture* has a public non-virtual non-explicit `const` conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's function call operator. **The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function** that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type's function call operator.

So your deleter is being initialized with a pointer to function, which remains valid even after you return from `func`.

Answer (score 0):

A little addition for implementation to the previous answers...

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_unique_with_deleter(T* t, D d)
{
    // granted copy elison since C++17
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D> (t, d);
}
```

using:

```
class A
{
};

auto up1 = make_unique_with_deleter(new A, [](A* a) {delete a; });
auto up2 = make_unique_with_deleter(std::fopen("something", "w"), std::fclose);

{
    int any_value = 0;
    // caution: only local use with lambda-capture, but possible
    auto up3 = make_unique_with_deleter(new A, [any_value](A* a) {delete a; });
}
```

A little quick solution. It works in different scenarios. It avoids the use on std:function with its little but unnecessary overhead.